# How to assign value from loop to variable using php?

Tags: php, sql

I am making a program that generates monthly report from the weekly report that is save from database. I can fetch the data from database through loop but the problem is i want to use the value from loop and assign it to a variable.

here's my code:

```
$mon=$_SESSION['mot'];
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keyper WHERE MONTH(date) = '$mon'");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
        {
            $tar1 =  $row2["target"];
            $hi = $row2["high1"];
            echo $tar1;
            echo $hi;
        }
```

After that query I got the result like this:

```
target1

high1

target2 

high2

target3

high3
```

I want to assign the result of the loop into a variable like this

```
$a="target1";
```

etc...

How can I do that? Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a counter variable($counter =1) and add counter to your  $tar.$counter =$row['target'] and $counter++ in end your loop

Comment: Please, please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.  mysql_escape_string if you insist on using inline variables, or use prepared statements http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you pass them into an array..

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
    $tar1[] =  $row2["target"]; //<--- The $tar1 variable is now an array
    $hi[] = $row2["high1"];     //<--- The $hi variable is now an array

}
```

So you access it like `echo $tar1[0];` that prints `target1` and `echo $hi[1];` will print `high2` etc and so on....

Comment: Wow! that is just the code that i needed. thank you so much. you save my life. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array to store the value..
like...

```
$tar1 = array();
$hi = array();
$i=0;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
     {
         $tar1[$i] =  $row2["target"];
         $hi[$i] = $row2["high1"]; 
         $i++;
     }
print_r($tar1);
print_r($hi);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
    $tar[$count][] =  $row2["target"]; //<--- The $tar1 variable is now an array
    $hi[$count][] = $row2["high1"];     //<--- The $hi variable is now an array
    $count++
}

foreach($tar as $key=>$targets)
{
echo $targets[0].$key;
}

just keep count in keys
```